# aspectj pointcut - intercept call from within javax.swing

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I create a `JMenuItem` which takes an anonymous inner class `AbstractAction`:

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Item") {
    @Override
    @Abc
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // ...
    }
});
```

I register this `JMenuItem` with a `MenuBar` which is registered to my Java Swing frame.
I have a pointcut which intercepts calls to @Abc methods

```
pointcut abcCall() :
    call(@Abc * *(..));
```

and advice for this pointcut:

```
Object around(): abcCall() {
    // ...
}
```

The call to actionPerformed will originate from inside javax.Swing, which I only have the binary for (rt.jar) - is it possible to compile-time weave javax.Swing to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not control the JDK classes, but your own code. So why not intercept method execution instead of call?

```java
pointcut abcCall() : execution(@Abc * *(..));
```

Answer (score 1):

probably, but youre talking about running the weaver against the whole jdk. the program will no longer be portable since it uses a modified jdk.

a better solution would be to create an abstract class that `extends AbstractAction`, and its `actionPerformed` method calls a common method that can be weaved, and is contained in your library.